# Split character vector containing annual report into sentences

Tags: r

I have read Microsoft's filings for 2016 into R. Now I want to clean the file, and split it into sentences. I have used the following code:

```
MSFT <- paste(readLines("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/000156459017014900/0001564590-17-014900.txt"), collapse = " ")
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you be more specific? When you say cleaning, what would you like to extract / filter out? Is it a certain tag you are interested in?

Comment: I want to extract the text from the filings (removing HTML tags, unnecessary punctuation, numbers, etc.) and then split the text into sentences.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way that you can try:

```
MSFT <- paste(readLines("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/000156459017014900/0001564590-17-014900.txt"), collapse = " ")
```

Remove everything from the text that is not within a `body` HTML tag (assupmtion: everything else is unwanted)

```
#Remove everything but body(s)
MSFT_body <- substr(MSFT, gregexpr("<body", MSFT)[[1]], gregexpr("</body", MSFT)[[1]])
```

Within the body, remove everything that is within `<` and `>` to get rid of HTML, CSS, aso...

```
#Remove all html tags and characters
MSFT_body_html_removed <- gsub("<.*?>|&[A-Za-z]+;|&#[0-9]+;", "", MSFT_body)
```

Remove all whitespace (i.e. spaces, line breaks, tabs,...) with 1 space

```
#Remove all whitespace and replace with space
MSFT_body_html_removed <- gsub("\\s+", " ", MSFT_body_html_removed)
```

You can use the `openNLP` sentence tokeniser (pretrained) to find sentences:

```
#Define function to tokenise text to sentences
sentence_tokeniser <- openNLP::Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator(language = "en")

#convert to String class
text <- NLP::as.String(MSFT_body_html_removed)
```

Use annotate to apply the tokeniser to the text

```
#Annotate text
annotated_sentences <- NLP::annotate(text, sentence_tokeniser)
```

Extract sentences

```
#extract sentences
sentences <- text[annotated_sentences]
```

Print first 5 sentences:

```
# print first 5 sentences  
for (i in 1:5) {
  print(paste("Sentence", i))
  cat(paste(sentences[i], "\n"))
}
```

This will give you:

```
[1] "Sentence 1"
UNITED STATES SECURITIES AND EXCHANGE COMMISSION Washington, D.C. 20549 FORM 10-K ANNUAL REPORT PURSUANT TO SECTION 13 OR 15(d) OF THE SECURITIES EXCHANGE ACT OF 1934 For the Fiscal Year Ended June 30, 2017 OR TRANSITION REPORT PURSUANT TO SECTION 13 OR 15(d) OF THE SECURITIES EXCHANGE ACT OF 1934 For the Transition Period From to Commission File Number 001-37845 MICROSOFT CORPORATION WASHINGTON 91-1144442 (STATE OF INCORPORATION) (I.R.S. ID) ONE MICROSOFT WAY, REDMOND, WASHINGTON 98052-6399 (425) 882-8080 www.microsoft.com/investor 
[1] "Sentence 2"
Securities registered pursuant to Section12(b) of the Act: COMMON STOCK, $0.00000625 par value per share NASDAQ Securities registered pursuant to Section12(g) of the Act: NONE Indicate by check mark if the registrant is a well-known seasoned issuer, as defined in Rule 405 of the Securities Act.YesNo Indicate by check mark if the registrant is not required to file reports pursuant to Section13 or Section15(d) of the Exchange Act.YesNo Indicate by check mark whether the registrant (1)has filed all reports required to be filed by Section13 or 15(d) of the Securities Exchange Act of 1934 during the preceding 12 months (or for such shorter period that the registrant was required to file such reports), and (2)has been subject to such filing requirements for the past 90 days.YesNo Indicate by check mark whether the registrant has submitted electronically and posted on its corporate website, if any, every Interactive Data File required to be submitted and posted pursuant to Rule 405 of Regulat... <truncated>
[1] "Sentence 3"
Indicate by check mark whether the registrant is a large accelerated filer, an accelerated filer, a non-accelerated filer, a smaller reporting company, or an emerging growth company. 
[1] "Sentence 4"
See the definitions of large accelerated filer, accelerated filer, smaller reporting company, and emerging growth company in Rule12b-2 of the Exchange Act. 
[1] "Sentence 5"
Large accelerated filer Acceleratedfiler Non-acceleratedfiler (Donotcheckifasmallerreportingcompany) Smallerreportingcompany Emerging growth company If an emerging growth company, indicate by check mark if the registrant has elected not to use the extended transition period for complying with any new or revised financial accounting standards provided pursuant to Section 13(a) of the Exchange Act.
```